# ul tag Binding Error using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application where i have to an ul tag. Here is my design view

```
<ul class="products_list" id="ulProductCart">                                       
        <li>
            <div class="clearfix">                  
                <img class="f_left m_right_10" src="" alt="">

                <div class="f_left product_description">
                    <a href="#" class="color_dark m_bottom_5 d_block"></a>
                    <span class="f_size_medium"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="f_left f_size_medium">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        1 x <b class="color_dark">$99.00</b>
                    </div>
                    <button class="close_product color_dark tr_hover"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

i am using jquery to bind this ul tag. Following is my jquery code to bind to the ul tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        id = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Default.aspx/BindCart",
            data: "{'UID':'" + id + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: OnImageSuccess,
            error: OnImageError,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('Fail');
            }
        });
        function OnImageSuccess(response) {                
            var ulProductCart = document.getElementById("ulProductCart");

            $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                ulProductCart.append("<li><div><img src=" + value.ImgProduct + " style=width:50px height:50px /><div><a>" + value.ProductName + "</a><span>" + value.ProductCode + "</div><div><div>1*<b>" + value.Price + "</b></div><button><i></i></button></div>  </div></li>");

            })
            alert('succeed');

        }
        function OnImageError(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
</script>
```

My Web Method is:

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    public static Products[] BindCart(string UID)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Products> details = new List<Products>();            

        //HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
        //a.InnerHtml

        dt = new ProductImages().SelectProductsWithImagesByProductID(Convert.ToInt64(UID));

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
        {
            Products Products = new Products();
            Products.ProductCode = dtrow["ProductCode"].ToString();
            Products.ProductName = dtrow["ProductName"].ToString();
            Products.ImgProduct = dtrow["ImgProduct"].ToString();
            Products.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(dtrow["Price"].ToString());
            details.Add(Products);
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

My above code fetches the appropriate data from database but when it goes to bind the ul tag it dows not gets bind.Also it goes to OnImageSuccess Mrthod used in jquery but my ul tag is not getting bind.

Comment: try `var ulProductCart = $('#ulProductCart')` or  `$(ulProductCart).append("<li><div...`

Comment: **Html** inside `ulProductCart.append()` are incorrectly formed. Inverted commas are missing in `style` properties also `<span>` tag is not ended properly. Roughly go through that **HTML** once again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue in the below line

```
var ulProductCart = document.getElementById("ulProductCart"); // not a jQuery object
```

`append` is a jQuery function , so u need to use jquery selector.

use this :

```
var ulProductCart = $("#ulProductCart");
```

Sample :

```
function OnImageSuccess(response) {                
               // var ulProductCart = document.getElementById("ulProductCart");
     var ulProductCart = $("#ulProductCart"); 
                $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                    ulProductCart.append("<li><div><img src=" + value.ImgProduct + " style=width:50px height:50px /><div><a>" + value.ProductName + "</a><span>" + value.ProductCode + "</div><div><div>1*<b>" + value.Price + "</b></div><button><i></i></button></div>  </div></li>");

                })
                alert('succeed');

            }
```